# Javascript code to click on google search bar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome extension to automatically focus on the google search bar so I can start typing my new search when I come to the tab without having to click the search bar again.

I have found how to access the google search bar by getElementByClassName but the focus does not seem to work for some reason.

document.getElementsByClassName("gLFyf gsfi")[0].focus();

I expect when I type the code above to the Google dev tools console, the search box should be focused.

Comment: Devtools console steals focus so it won't work. You need to do it in your content script. Also, document.getElementsByName('q')[0] is a better way to access it since you won't rely on the temporary class names that may change often.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help. I am just a newbie so could you please help me a bit more understanding how document.getElementsByName('q')[0] would work out better?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code works, it is just that Google wrote css that changes the focus behaviour. In the following screenshot, you can see that the input outline was set to none:

[image]

I guess you could set the style of the field to the hover style after you used the focus as a workaround.

Comment: Thank you.
Could you help me a bit more with understanding what you mean by setting the style of the field to the hover style?
I'm just starting to learn css and js

Comment: Well, you can access the style property after you selected the element. For example I use a querySelector to get the element:
const sa = document.querySelector("input[name=q]")
And then set it's style like this: 
sa.style = "background: red"
So you can write css in the style property. You could look up in the developer tools what they apply on hover and copy it and set it manually via the style.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you so much!